# Appium support on Firebase Test Lab

Tags: android, firebase, appium

Does anyone know if Appium Testing Framework is going to be supported on Firebase Test Lab? Is it in at least the roadmap?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a question specifically directed toward Firebase support rather than the Stack Overflow community at large.  Support questions should go directly to Firebase support. https://firebase.google.com/support/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Firebase is powered by Google, you hardly can expect it prioritise supporting open-source community driven framework, which Appium is.

Currently Firebase supports native frameworks only: Espresso, Robotium and UI Automator 2.0 (2 of 3 are supported and driven by Google) I don't think Google use Appium internally.

Since they started Beta support of iOS XCTest, looks like iOS native frameworks is current priority.

You still can write to Firebase support, but my guess native frameworks is the final scope of firebase support and if you are interested in using particular Appium, there are plenty of other services to try out.